# Remove ebs volume forcefully -powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Below command is not working for me ? Do I need to add some more info to remove/delete the ebs volume.

```
Remove-EC2Volume -VolumeId $volume -Force
```

Thanks

Comment: is there an error message? or is not functioning?

Comment: As I am running through cloudformation there is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try appending 'aws eC2' along with the command as below for AWS CLI,

```
aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id vol-049df61146c4d7901
```

If you are using PowerShell then,

```
Remove-EC2Volume -VolumeId vol-12345678
```

or

```
Remove-EC2Volume -VolumeId <String> -PassThru <SwitchParameter> -Force <SwitchParameter>
```

Please see definition of each parameter [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Remove-EC2Volume.html)

Comment: Will this work? as I am using in PowerShell.. I am referring to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-deleting-volume.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you are using PowerShell. Updated answer for PowerShell. Also added a link to your reference.

Answer (score 0):

We need to dismount and then remove the disk !!!
Dismount-EC2Volume -VolumeId $volume
Remove-EC2Volume -VolumeId $volume -Force